# Properties end being null in some cases but containing static variable is not

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties, null, static-members

Sorry if i dont explain myself clearly but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to present the problem at hand.

We have some utility classes used in web and windows forms development. We use the following pattern in order to dynamically call the corresponding methods depending on whether the code runs inside a web or in windows forms.

The following code is a stripped down version so you can observe the logic clearlier:

```
public static class Constants
{
    private static ConstantsWinFormsWebCommonProvider _Provider;

    public static ConstantsWinFormsWebCommonProvider Provider
    {
        get
        {  /*in websites the static variables reset to null in case of Appdomain recycle
            *so we check beforehand, this also serves for first time use in both: web and winforms */
            //lazy loading, initializes when provider is required for the first time or if gets null because appdomain recycle...
            if (_Provider != null) return _Provider;

            _Provider = Fun.WebSite()? (ConstantsWinFormsWebCommonProvider)new ConstantsWebProvider() : new ConstantsWinFormsProvider();

            Initialize();
            return _Provider;
        }
    }
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        Provider.Initialize();
    }
    public static string DataBaseName 
    {
        get { return Provider.DataBaseName ; }
        set { Provider.DataBaseName = value; }
    }
}

public class ConstantsWinFormsWebCommonProvider
{
    internal bool isInitialized { get; set; } //variable only used in the winform part for now, shouldnt affect the web part issue
    internal string DataBaseName { get; set; }
}

public class ConstantsWebProvider: ConstantsWinFormsWebCommonProvider
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();

        string errordetails= "";
        if (!Fun.InitializeWeb(ref errordetails)) //fills all the Provider properties and connects, otherwise returns false
        {
            throw new Exception("Problem initializating web " + errordetails));
        }
    }
}

public class ConstantsWinFormsProvider: ConstantsWinFormsWebCommonProvider
{
    public new string DataBaseName 
    {
        get
        {//lazy loading so it connects only when required
            if (isInitialized) //(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(base.DataBaseName))
            {
                return base.DataBaseName ;
            }
            bool resul = Fun.InicializeWinForms();

            if (resul) return base.DataBaseName ;

            MessageBox.Show("Problem initializing");
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            Fun.WinFormsValueSavingSistemx(value); //example call, not related with the issue at hand
        }
    }
}
```

---

The problem is that occasionally in the case of the web we get errors because the properties inside the Provider variable are null, but the Provider itself is not null.

In theory it shouldn't be possible (in the case of the web we initialize all the Provider properties in the Initialize() function and if the appdomain recycles causing the properties to go null the Provider variable should be null too causing it to call Initialize() again when you try to access one of its properties).

What's the cause and recommended solution to this problem?

Edit: 
In case this provides more hindsight, the problem for now has happened in the first page load of one aspx (isPostback = false, where it would access the Provider.DataBaseName for the first time in the first visit to that aspx or if coming again from another aspx). Also in the documented cases they where using IE8 and IE9...

Comment: Ive had the same problem w/ some static methods on webservers before. I opened a ticket w/ Microsoft and they said it was a threading issue and they dont always behave like WPF. May want to look into threading/static methods.

Comment: @Anon In my case the place where it occurs is in the first page load of an aspx, no (explicit) threading used in the code

Comment: Yeah I actually didnt write any threading code w/ my issue, it was the server when handling multiple clients. Sorry I can be of any more assistance.

Comment: @Anon thanks for the tip anyway. Did you get from microsoft some link to check the issue or a link to the ticket?